# Augmented Reality: Rendering a Android webView in 3D Mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview, augmented-reality

I want to develop an Android app that has capability to show Webview in 3d mode.


I found very useful [android plugin](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview) but this plugin only support 2D.

Please give me suggestion on it.

Thank you in advance.

Also found same functionality in ARkit:

- https://www.viget.com/articles/using-arkit-and-image-tracking/
- https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/building-a-gesture-based-interface-ios-app-with-core-ml-and-arkit-910b5c94da80